# react native reanimated animation works on once

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am using reanimated to create a custom alert inside a modal, it works fine but the animation will work only once in the beginning after that modal is visible and the contents are updated but animation won't work,

here is my code

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    // stopClock(clock);
    if (this.state.visible) {
      block([
        timing(this.val, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 100,
          easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
        }).start(),
        spring(this.scale, {
          toValue: 1,
          damping: 12,
          mass: 0.6,
          stiffness: 150.6,
          overshootClamping: false,
          restSpeedThreshold: 0.1001,
          restDisplacementThreshold: 0.001,
        }).start(),
      ]);
    } else {
      block([
        timing(this.val, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 0,
          easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
        }).start(),
        spring(this.scale, {
          toValue: 0,
          damping: 12,
          mass: 0.6,
          stiffness: 150.6,
          overshootClamping: false,
          restSpeedThreshold: 0.001,
          restDisplacementThreshold: 0.001,
        }).start(),
      ]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to add animation values to zero before running the animations like:-

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    // stopClock(clock);
   //Setting animations values as zero
    this.val.setValue(0);
    this.scale.setValue(0);
    if (this.state.visible) {
      block([
        timing(this.val, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 100,
          easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
        }).start(),
        spring(this.scale, {
          toValue: 1,
          damping: 12,
          mass: 0.6,
          stiffness: 150.6,
          overshootClamping: false,
          restSpeedThreshold: 0.1001,
          restDisplacementThreshold: 0.001,
        }).start(),
      ]);
    } else {
      block([
        timing(this.val, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 0,
          easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
        }).start(),
        spring(this.scale, {
          toValue: 0,
          damping: 12,
          mass: 0.6,
          stiffness: 150.6,
          overshootClamping: false,
          restSpeedThreshold: 0.001,
          restDisplacementThreshold: 0.001,
        }).start(),
      ]);
    }
  }
```